# Workflow for going from Numpy to Embedded C?

Tags: numpy, embedded

I'm pretty new with Embedded C, but I've got some operations on numpy arrays that I think I would like to try to put into an embedded system.

I can't seem to find any documentation or recommendations on this, but I would imagine there is a recommended workflow.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you build and test your algorithms in C, targeting your development machine, using the same size variables as are being considered on the embedded system (in explicit portable form, such as `uint16_t` or whatever).  It's drastically easier to debug the implementation of an algorithm in a setting where you can inject test data and capture and plot outputs or intermediate values as needed.  You could probably even pipe the program's stdout back into python for analysis - and then when you move to the embedded board up, do the same with serial data coming back from the board.

Comment: There is a section in the numpy reference manual on its C-API.  http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformancePython compares various ways of speeding up numpy, such as `weave` and `f2py`.  `cython` seems to be the current darling.  http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html